# Toggle JSON file i read in

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a function that runs my code given that I pass through a JSON file. I did this so I can change the file via a button not via code.

```
tryOutChange(JSONFILE) // this holds the main bulk of code.
changeJSON() // this is a button that runs the function above.
```

This function first deletes the old 'g' elements that hold the nodes and edges (my force directed graph) and then runs the main code with a different JSON file. This way I can click the same button and swap which JSON file i read.

```
var networkJSONfile = true;
    function changeJSON()
    {
        var oldForce = document.getElementById("forceLayout");
    oldForce.parentNode.removeChild(oldForce);

        if(networkJSONfile == true){
        tryOutChange(engine);
        networkJSONfile = false;
        } else if(networkJSONfile == false){
            tryOutChange(network);
            networkJSONfile = true;
        }
    }
```

This works. But only once. When I go to create one of the graphs i recently deleted it wont create the graph again ? Have I deleted the JSON file too by anychance or ?

Network and Engine are JSON files

Here is what happens.

I run the `tryOutChange()` and pass the `'network'` JSON file to it straight away so it comes up with a network viewer.

I then click a button which runs the `changeJSON()` function.

This function deletes everything I created previously when I called `tryOutChange()`. and then calls that function again with `Engines JSON`.

When I click the button again it does the same this. Deletes what I have created, then called that `tryOutChange()` function using the Network JSON. And so on. So in theory, it should toggle JSON files from network to engine on click.

When i first click it, its fine, it deletes the network and shows the engine, but when i want to go back and recreate the network uising `network JSON` it doesnt work ?

Comment: can you be sure that `engine` and `network` are valid json? We'll need to see more code. Where is this code in relation to where the `network` and `engine` vars are being set?

Comment: theyre just files in the same directory. I presume theyre valid JSON as when i run them on their own it works, as in, run them the first time. But when I go back to the first JSON file, (as in call the function again with the starting JSON file) it comes up with an error.

Comment: can we see the code that binds the click event to the `changeJSON` handler?

Comment: as in the onClick call ?

Comment: yes, please post all the click event code

Comment: all it is is a rectangle so when its clicked (i.e .on('click', function(){ return changeJSON();})) so it calls the function in the question ? :/

Comment: if you can be sure that the method `changeJSON` is being called everytime you click the button, then your problem is with `tryOutChange` call... can we see that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70306/discussion-between-rekodolph-and-shennan).